# Many viewers, one or several content providers / domain model in eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, jface, tableviewer

I have question about using model, contentprovider and table viewers in Eclipse RCP.

I can't find any suitable tutorial or example to this topic.

What is the proper way to design data model that should be displayed in more than one table viewer. Do I have to create content provider for each viewer or only one instance of content provider for several viewers that display the same data?

Another question. If I have to create many instances of content provider do I have to create one instance of domain model or several instances for each content provider?

I would like to notify each viewer if the model has changed (add element / remove element / update element) to update view to the user? In the internet there are many tutorials and examples but they based only on one viewer scenario. Can somebody put some more light on this topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please find the answers below

1. Each viewer needs a content provider instance. This can be one class used by all viewers or  create new content provider implementation for each viewer. The content provider's role is to convert your data model into a form which the viewer can understand. If you displaying the same data in all the viewers I would suggest to have one implementation of content provider & create multiple instance for each viewer. You can assign the same instance to all viewers, but I wouldn't suggest that.
2. You don't have to create multiple instance of your datamodel. You can reuse the same instance.
3. Ideally what works for one viewer will also work for multiple. I don't know what tutorial you are referring to, if you could post the link then maybe I could suggest.

Comment: Thank You. I just figured out that each viewer needs separate content provider. During disposing Viewer is turning off it's content provider  by calling it's methods inputChange and then dispose. If you have viewers in separate Views or Dialogs then content provider should be provided for each viewer. The Model or inputElement should be singleton and any changes in model should notify all content providers that using this model.

Comment: If you look at the inputChange method, its takes the viewer as a parameter, so technically the content provider should not be effected by this. unless you have declared some class variables...